# Rails 3.1 .css.less caching error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, less

I am quite new with Rails and I am having some irritating problems with caching of css files.

I have a .css.less file with imports inside it. It's the only stylesheet the app includes, so the other files get imported only once and by this unique stylesheet.
One of those imported .css.less stylesheets seems to be cached somewhere, because does not change in the browser when I change it's source.

I can only see the changes I made if I change something in the root stylesheet.

I have the server in development mode, so the caching should be off. I have also used `<%= stylesheet_include_tag "style", :cache => false %>`

I tried with Chrome and Firefox, with and without clearing their cache too. Always the same result, if I work only on that file the css the page receives when reloaded doesn't have the changes...

I also stopped the server and rm everything in the tmp folder of the app. No changes.

I am using Rails 3.1 with Ruby 1.9.3, with the less-bootstrap-rails gem. Both the root stylesheet and the imported one have .css.less extension.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is an area where I think the asset pipeline is broken, but I don't think there's a good fix.

If I remember correctly, to get changes in files you've included/required in your .css.less file, you need to change the .css.less file itself.

Answer (score 3):

I had this on Rails 4.0.8, infuriating.  The config changes mentioned above didn't help.  Here's what seems to have fixed it for me:

- Ensure NO FILES share a base name.  For example, you have a reports.css.less and a reports.js.coffee?  Doesn't matter if they're in the same directory or not.  Rename or delete one of them.  (I changed it to reports-styles.css.less).
- Blow away your cache: rm -rf tmp/cache
- Restart your Rails app.

This appears to be a decent fix but, since I don't know what's actually going on, this could be totally false and it's just working by coincidence now.  Sorry this answer isn't more rigorous!

Comment: If I hadn't run into the exact same problem, I would have thought you were on crack.  Another way to clear out cached CSS: `$ rake assets:clobber`

Answer (score 1):

I've just came across the exact same problem.

I found that if you rename your `*.css.less` file (the one with the imports inside) to `*.less`, then this weird cacheing problem gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your config/application.rb

```
# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

See more at: [Ruby on Rails Guide: Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: That is already in the application.rb. Btw from what I understand from the guide is needed when upgrading from an older versione, and that's not my case.

Comment: This doesn't work in Rails 4, and neither does `    config.assets.configure { |env| env.cache = ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:null_store) }`.  Near as I can tell, with Rails 4, we just have to live with it.  Awful.  :(